# Premature memoization on obvious cases

Tags: python, optimization, python-3.x

In the code below there will be several instances of `MainClass`.

```
class MainClass(object):

    def f(self, x):
        # expensive operations.
        # ...
        return 'something'
```

Each instance calls `f(x)` several times and `x` has a specific value that doesn't change during those calls.

Since `f()` is somewhat expensive, I can use the decorator [`@functools.lru_cache()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools.html) to memoize the calls.

However, I am worried that this is premature optimization.

---

Questions:

- Would it be dangerous to use `lru_cache()` from now?
- Should I not care at all about which pieces of my code can be
  optimized (even if they are obvious to spot, and easy to optimize)?
- Should I ignore memoization on obvious cases completely, or perhaps note it (e.g. `#TODO comments`) so that it's easier later on when time for optimization comes?

<sub>(Note: My actual code is +10k LOC and I am the only dev working on it.)</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would typically use memoization where you have established that the problem that your function is trying to solve has optimal substructure.  This means that the larger problem can be broken well into a series of small subproblems.  It sounds as if you were successful in realizing this and that you solved this in a recursive way, which is also a way of breaking down a large problem into subproblems.

If you have working code and it satisfies all requirements including non-functional requirements on performance and scalability then you don't necessarily need to improve the performance of the code by using memoization.  Delaying the release of working software to optimize is generally the spirit of "Avoid premature optimization" in my humble opinion.

> Would it be dangerous to use lru_cache() from now?

It depends on how you define danger.  If you have a working recursive solution without memoization then the only real danger here is possibly adding more complexity which increases the risk of introducing a bug into your logic.  The other risk is that you might delay the release of the software to work on an optimization that isn't necessary based on clearly defined non-functional requirements.

I might even argue though that if you have a long running recursive function then there might actually be danger in NOT using memoization!

What I mean by this is that for a sufficiently large dataset you run the risk of blowing the stack or running out of memory.  You should do adequate stress testing to ensure that your recursive solution is fine.

> Should I not care at all about which pieces of my code can be optimized (even if they are obvious to spot, and easy to optimize)?

If it is an easy optimization then by all means go for it.  Premature optimization avoidance isn't so much a hard and fast rule as it is a guideline for living ones life as a developer.  It is inspired by some other subjective guidelines like YAGNI and KISS.

> Should I ignore memoization on obvious cases completely, or perhaps note it (e.g. #TODO comments) so that it's easier later on when time for optimization comes?

Absolutely.  I think TODO's are a great way to leave little post-its for yourself and other developers about where something could be improved or done better.  That is also a matter of personal preference though.  Pro-TODO and Anti-TODO developers though have very strong opinions on either side and they both make good points.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how this would be “dangerous” (The additional maintenance burden you take on is very modest, after all.) but you should benchmark it to be sure that is actually improves something.

If benchmarking sounds like too much trouble at this point, then it probably *is* a premature optimization and you should just forget about it for now.  Profile your code later when you encounter a need for optimization and see if this is a point where your optimization efforts will be well spent.

Answer (score 1):

If the expensive operations have side-effects then they should be preserved. In other words this function will then not be a candidate for memoization.

If they don't and the output is constant like in your example, then why is there an expensive operation there in the first place?

Whether memoization actually helps depends on how it's used. Is the result cached anyway then it won't make a difference (it'll actually be worse because of the caching logic).